# Google Play services out of date. Requires 10084000 but found 8703430

Tags: android

I can not get fairebase notification token in android studio
error: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
and
Google Play services out of date.  Requires 10084000 but found 8703430
i use dependencies
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1"

Comment: Did you updated SDK ?

Comment: update your device google play services app

Comment: sir I use android studio 2.2.3

Comment: Android SDK Platform-Tools 25.0.3, Android SDK Tools 25.2.4